# simplify system of equations -- any relation with golden ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, golden-ratio

I have a system of equations:

$w(1-v) = v(1+u) \tag{1}$

$(w-1)(u+1) = v-u^2 \tag{2}$

$u^2 (v+1)(w+3)+2 u v (w+1)-v (w+3)+w-1=0 \tag{3}$

First, I would like to know if this system of equations could be further simplified (specially the third equation). You can assume that $u,v,w$ are real numbers with values close to $u=0.389, v=0.469, w=1.229$.

Second (bonus question): Are the solutions to this system related in any interesting way to the *golden ratio* $\phi$.

Edit: I added a figure below to give an idea where $u,v,w$ came from. In this figure, $u,v,w$ are the (absolute value of) inverse of the slope of the green, red and blue lines.

[image]

Comment: $$u = -1, v = 1$$

Comment: @Moo,  u,v, and w should be close to 0.389, 0.469, 1.229 respectively

Comment: I know you said that in the problem statement, but below you say that "but u=0.389 does not seem to be a solution to this (?) ". Which is it? There are three real solution and you now have two of them.

Comment: @mghandi: Yes, the three cubics that define $u,v,w$ have coefficients that are powers of the _golden ratio_. See my answer below.

Comment: @mghandi: By the way, how did you know beforehand that it could be related to the golden ratio?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I guessed it. It came up during my effort to understand and expand the infinite queen problem described here by the legendary Don Knuth: https://youtu.be/BxQw4CdxLr8?t=57m6s

Comment: @mghandi: Please see my answer for the simple connection to golden ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots $u,\,v,\,w = 0.389, 0.469, 1.229$ are roots of cubics with coefficients that are *powers* of the *golden ratio* $\phi$ namely,

$$u^3 - 3\phi^2 u^2 + \phi^6u - \phi^2\sqrt{5} = 0$$ 
$$v^3 + 3\phi^{-2}v^2 + \phi^{-6}v - \phi^{-2} = 0$$
$$w^3 + 3w^2 + \phi^{-2}w - \phi^4 = 0$$

---

**Edit:** Courtesy of Somos' answer, we have,

$$u = \phi-w\\
v = w/\phi^2$$

I find $w$ can also be expressed as the nice cubic,

$$\frac{(w+1)^3}{w+3}=\phi^2$$

Using *trigonometric or hyperbolic functions*, we can solve it simply as,

> $$w = -1+\frac{2\,\phi\,\cos\left(\tfrac13\,\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}{\phi}\right)\right)}{\sqrt3} \approx 1.229$$
>   $$w = -1+\frac{2\,\phi\,\cosh\left(\tfrac13\,\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}{\phi}\right)\right)}{\sqrt3} \approx 1.229 $$

where $\cos^{-1}x=\text{arccos}\,x$. More traditionally,

$$w = -1+x_1^{1/3}+x_2^{1/3}\approx 1.229\tag{1.1}$$

and $x_i$ are the two roots of,

$$x^2-2\phi^2\,x+\frac{\phi^6}{27}=0$$

---

$\color{blue}{\text{Further edit:}}$ To address a comment of the OP, the solution to the general cubic,

$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$

is,

> $$3x = -a+z_1^{1/3}+z_2^{1/3}\tag1$$

where the $z_i$ are the two roots of the quadratic Lagrange resolvent,

$$z^2 + (2 a^3 - 9 a b + 27 c) z + (a^2 - 3 b)^3 = 0$$

Alternatively,

> $$3x = -a+z_1^{1/3}+\frac{a^2-3b}{z_1^{1/3}}\tag2$$

where $z_1$ is any non-zero root of the resolvent.

The advantage of $(1)$ is it somehow more symmetrical (which I prefer), while the advantage of $(2)$ is you take the cube root of only one value (which is the default of *Mathematica*) and is useful when the $z_i$ are complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please elaborate a bit about your method. This looks quite interesting. I guess this could still be further simplified (maybe by some change of variables). I will try to add a graph that may help.

Comment: @mghandi: Like Graubner and Somos, I reduced the system to one equation in one variable. Then factored over $\sqrt{5}$. (I use _Mathematica_.)  Recognizing that the coefficients were powers of the golden ratio is a combination of intuition and calculation. But the fact they are such neat powers means there's something about the system that led you to suspect the golden ratio was involved.

Comment: @Somos: Very nice simplifications for $u,v$. The simplest I could find for $w$ is $$\phi^2 = \frac{(w+1)^3}{w+3}$$ To mghandi: Since the minpolys of your system are sextics, I'm afraid you will have to use a square root and cube root somewhere.

Comment: I was unable to verify the last equation. Here is what I got: $w = -1 + \frac{1+\phi}{\tau}+ \frac{\tau}{3}$ where $\tau = 3^{1/3}(9+9\phi+\sqrt{3}\sqrt{49+73\phi})^{1/3}\approx 5.166$.

Comment: @mghandi: I've reviewed $(1.1)$ and it does give $w\approx 1.229$ so I believe your comment is on how I got that form. I've added a further edit to describe ***two*** approaches to solving the general cubic equation. Actually, there is a ***third*** approach which might yield an even better form. Give me a while to sort it out.

Comment: @mghandi: Done. The third approach is to use _trigonometric or hyperbolic functions_ and which can concisely express your $w$.

Answer (score 2):

The three equations can be written as polynomials in $u,v,w$ as:
$p_1 := w (1-v)-v (1+u)=0,\quad p_2 := (w-1) (u+1)-v+u^2=0,$
$p_3:= u^2 (v+1) (w+3)+2 u v (w+1)-v (w+3)+w-1=0.$

We use [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)
where $\textrm{res}_x(p(x),q(x))$ is the resultant of  polynomials in variable $x$. Compute
$r_1 := \textrm{res}_v(p_1,p_2)/(u+1),\quad$
$r_2 := \textrm{res}_v(p_1,p_3)/(u+1),\quad$
$r_3 := \textrm{res}_u(p_1,p_2)/(v-1),\quad$
$r_4 := \textrm{res}_u(p_1,p_3)/(v-1),\quad$
$p_u := \textrm{res}_w(r_1,r_2) =
u^6 -9u^5 +27u^4 -26u^3 +u^2 +15u -5,$
$p_v := -\textrm{res}_w(r_3,r_4)/v^4 =
v^6 +9v^5 +27v^4 +18v^3 -5v^2 -7v +1,\quad$
$p_w =\textrm{res}_u(r_1,r_2) =
w^6 +6w^5 +12w^4 +2w^3 -20 w^2 -18w +1.$

$p_u,p_v,p_w\;$ are irreducible. Note that $\;u = \phi-w,\;\;v = w/\phi^2,\;$  and $\;u v - w (u-v+w-1) = 0.$

Note that $u=-1,v=1$ is a solution to all three of the original equations.

Edit: There is still the mystery of equation $(3)$. How to get it given the numerical values of $\;u,v,w.$
That is, using the PARI/GP function $\texttt{lindep(v)}$ I found linear relations between $(u,v,w,\phi)$ and I can find polynomial equations like $p_1$ and $p_2,$ but they are satisfied if $u=\phi-w,\; v=w/\phi^2,\;$ and so far I can't get another integer polynomial in $\;u,v,w\;$ that I can solve for $\;w.$

Comment: Thanks. Could you please check pv and pw. The solution (u=0.389, v=0.469, w=1.229) does not seem to satisfy these.  These equations (including p3) arised from a simple geometric problem that is related to an interesting problem in combinatorics.

Comment: I fixed my typos. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The last two terms for p_v should be -7v +1 (instead of +7v +1).

Comment: Although these are interesting results, they are not really what I was looking for. I want to find a more simplified representation (for example in terms of total number of terms or symmetry) to make sense of these three numbers (u=0.389..., v=0.469..., w=1.229...).

Comment: Okay, I fixed my last typo. Making sense is tough.

Comment: Yes that is indeed the simpler system of equations I was looking for.Thanks Somos. Similar to the question I asked @TitoPiezasIII could you please elaborate on your method.

Comment: I see. So, for $w$, currently the cubic form (the third equation in @TitoPiezasIII 's solution) is the simplest form we have so far. I am positive that it could also be further simplified or at least be written in a more interpretable form.

Answer (score 1):

eliminating step by step the variables we get for $u$ the equation
$$(u^6-9u^5+27u^4-26u^3+u^2-15u-5)(u+1)=0$$
by a numerical method we get
$${u = 0.3892773008780011471324554158555669542330590528674325981347375567503\dots\\ v = 0.4693432908633176939543775508532342246571802975697442128254750629456 \dots\\ w = 1.2287566878718937010721314185100711634872501269383302640007110659549\dots}$$

Comment: thanks. but u=0.389 does not seem to be a solution to this (?)

Comment: i will try to solve the equation above by a numerical method,ok?

Comment: thanks. The question is that what these numbers are? What is a simpler form to represent them ?

Comment: @mghandi:  there is no guarantee that there is a simpler form.  Starting at degree $5$ there are polynomials whose solutions cannot be expressed with radicals.  I put the first two into the [inverse symbolic calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) and it didn't find anything.

Comment: @RossMillikan: The sextic factors over $\sqrt{5}$, hence $u \approx 0.389$ is a root of the cubic $$u^3 - 3\phi^2 u^2 + \phi^6u - \phi^2 \sqrt{5} = 0$$ with _golden ratio_ $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks TitoPiezasIII. I am wondering if the other two equations (p_v and p_w in @Somos 's answer) would similarly further simplify ?

Comment: @mghandi: Yes, they do.